# Uninstall the 64-bit version of Internet Explorer 8 (Windows 7)

Tags: 64-bit, internet-explorer-8, uninstall

Can I uninstall or override the 64-bit version of Internet Explorer, so that it won't get activated as the default browser?

I would like to leave the 32-bit version installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you made some changes to your system, Internet Explorer 32-bit should be the default browser.

I'm not sure what Windows version you're running, but in Windows 7 64-bit, by default, IE8 32-bit automatically runs when you start the browser from any one of the following locations:

- The Quick Launch toolbar
- The desktop
- The Start menu
- A hyperlink or a file type that is associated with Internet Explorer

If you want to see which version is currently running, check the Help -> About Internet Explorer window. The 64-bit version will note that it's the 64-bit version.

If you truly want to uninstall Internet Explorer, you'll have to remove both versions following [these steps from Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957700).

Comment: I.e. You need to take specific steps to make the 64bit IE the default.

Answer (score 2):

According to the specialists at **Microsoft Social Answers**, you cannot "remove" or uninstall IE8 64-bit in Windows 7 without removing IE8 32-bit; you can only disable access to it. See the full thread [here](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/InternetExplorer/thread/8ae3464e-e86a-4b09-b795-4e96340a8bc1) for further information. You can also take a look at a similar thread [here](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/InternetExplorer/thread/a500a88a-682d-4bb6-9c30-c3bb91748938).

Answer (score 1):

From what I've read on my Windows 7 Professional install, IE 8 64-bit can't be set as the default browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a normal Software Restriction policy to block visiting 64 Bit IE. You can also use script or other Group Policy settings to remove 64 Bit IE shortcuts on clients.

64 Bit IE is installed in the following folder:
C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer

32 Bit IE was installed in the folder below:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer

NOTE: If you need to only effect 64-bit machines, you can use a WMI filter to target only 64 bit OS. Use the following:

select * from win32_operatingsystem where osarchitecture="64-bit"

Reference from the following website:
http://anonit.blogspot.de/2012/12/create-group-policy-wmi-filter-to.html