# How to uninstall Internet Explorer 64 bit

Tags: 64-bit, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Uninstall the 64-bit version of Internet Explorer 8 (Windows 7)](https://superuser.com/questions/117795/uninstall-the-64-bit-version-of-internet-explorer-8-windows-7)

It seems I have two separate Internet Explorers. How do I uninstall the 64-bit version?

Comment: Which OS? Why do you want yo uninstall it ?

Comment: You cannot remove just the 64-bit - more details - [Uninstall the 64 bit version of Internet Explorer 8 (Windows 7)](http://superuser.com/questions/117795/uninstall-the-64-bit-version-of-internet-explorer-8-windows-7)

Comment: Do you mean that when you click on IE both versions launch at once? Please tell us with Windows and IE version. Uninstalling one of the versions is not the solution.

Comment: I believe that your problem here is not really uninstalling IE 64-bit. I suggest you start up a new post with the root problem well explained.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows 7 I believe there is an option to easily remove the core components. If you are using an earlier version of Windows I do not believe there is any easy way to uninstall the core Internet Explorer. Bear in mind that all recent versions of Windows use the rendering engine of Internet Explorer for various things, and you won't be able to completely remove all of Internet Explorer without seriously crippling the operating system.

*[How do I uninstall or remove Internet Explorer as a troubleshooting step?](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957700)* link will take you though the steps.

However, why do you want to uninstall it? You should be able to use the 32-bit version without any issues, or whatever your alternative brand of choice is.

Comment: when i open internet explorer i get 2 versions at once